# Which function is overridden first in Android

Tags: java, android, oop

Which function is overridden first in following

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
```

and why?
If anyone have answer please tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean overridden as in which one is called first, then onMeasure should be called first before onDraw because the widgets needs to be measured first before they are drawn.

If you are trying to set a size to widgets in onDraw then it is a bad idea.